# Azure no subscription listed when create new service namespace

Tags: azure

i'm starting in Windows Azure.
I tried to create a new service namespace following the tutorial https://www.windowsazure.com/zh-cn/develop/net/tutorials/multi-tier-application/
However, no subscription is list in the combo, i don't know why. As illustrated in the pic.
sorry, i'm not allowed to post image.

p.s. i'm a manager, not co-manager.And i'm in china(does this matter?)

any tips?
many thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ensure that the live ID you are using was properly associated with a valid subscription?

Also, China is not currently a supported country for Windows Azure. So I presume the subscription may have been created for you by a 3rd party vendor (or friend). So you will want to verify with them that the subscripion was properly setup. Additionally, given that you are in an unsupported region for purchase, you may nee to wok with that vendor to help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: it's a education account, and my live id is registered using google mail account. this is not proper?!

Comment: p.s. trivial .NET MVC app can be published on Azure

Comment: Educational account shouldn't matter. But again I'd check with the administrator/owner of the subscription to make sure there aren't any limits on the account that you're not aware of. I recently learned that some subscriptions can't create services in some zone's if they've been restricted from it.

Comment: Ok, i figure it out by accident.. =.=
i use co-admin account instead and retry, the subscription just came out...
but i don't know why. admin account is more privileged, isn't it?
Thank you for you reply.